# How to assign value returned by a function into a variable?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to determine the sceen width using media query then properly display the results retreived from database. For now results are shown using a function this way. This function actually to display dropdown list for a particular menu.

```
<?php Core::getHook('block-branches'); ?>
```

So tried something as below to display content according to screen width:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['width'])) {
    $width = $_GET['width'];
    if ($width <= 480) { //mobile devices
      $list =  Core::getHook('home-menu-mobile'); **//assigning function value into a variable**
    } elseif ($width <= 720){ //tablets
      $list = Core::getHook('home-menu-mobile'); **//assigning function value into a variable**
    } else { //desktops
      $list = Core::getHook('block-branches'); **//assigning function value into a variable**
    }

  } 
?>
```

HTML

```
<select id="myselect">
   <option>Go To ...</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/">Home</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/page/about-us">About Us &#9662;</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/page/the-centre-point-of-any-web-projects">Centre-Point of Web Projects</option>
   <option><a href="#">Branches &#9662;</a>

        <?php echo $list;?>**(display according to screen width)**

</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/news">News</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/event">Events</option>
   <option value="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/contact">Contact Us</option>
</select>

<script>
    //$('#myselect').on('change', function() {
  //location.href=$(this).data('url');
//});
document.getElementById("myselect").onchange = function(d){
  window.location = this.value;
};
    </script>
```

Comment: what is smtg up there?

Comment: which type of trouble you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the **function** **getHook**('block-branches') is returning an array not a value so you must loop the **$list** and display the value like this

```
       <option><a href="#">Branches &#9662;</a>
        <?php foreach($list as $value){

          echo $value;
         }?>**(display according to screen width)**

         </option>
```